# Center text in SVG with React

Tags: javascript, html, svg, text, center

First of all, yes, I have searched and I have seen the many other answers available. But they didn't work for me.

I would like to be able to center the text in my SVG.

Since I have to be able to put it left, center or right, (both horizontally and vertically) I tried to be a little bit generic and compute x and y programmatically.

Here is an example : https://codesandbox.io/s/ll6ppwkyq7

You can see in the result that the text is not vertically centered.

The red box is the bounding box of the text.

The black box is the box in which I am supposed to be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between **x** coordinate of an element and the coordinate of the **right** position of the text is not the same as of the **y** coordinate of an element and the **bottom** position. In fact it's inverted.

That's because vertically, the text is place at the bottom of an element and y coordinates go from top to bottom, while horizontally coordinates go in the same direction as the text.

This is easily seen when using GetBBbox() method, which you are using. For example, when adding a text element at coordinates 0 for x and y, you'll see that **getBBbox** will give you a x = 0 but a negative y.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('testbbox').getBBox());
```

```html
<svg id="testbbox"><text x=0 y=0>test</text></svg>
```

So already, calculations to center your text will need to be different. What you have now is:

```
outerRect.x - ((outerRect.width - innerRect.width) / 2)
```

This works because you assume that inner rectangle starts from 0, which is not the case. Your bounding box is vertically in the negative. So complete formula should be something like:

```
outerRect.x - innerRect.x - ((outerRect.width - innerRect.width) / 2)
```

Which in your example would be:

```
x - bboxx + ( (width - boxWidth) / 2)
```

Where **bbox** is **x** of **getBBox()**

You could use baseline, but with **dy** on the **tspan**, it makes the calculations a bit more complex, not sure it's the good approach. Since anyway **getBBox** takes baseline into account in the calculation, it's not really necessary.

Also, if you look here, baseline for text should be dominant-baseline, not alignement-baseline: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline

See how it affects the bounding box, especially **y** coordinate:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('central').getBBox());
console.log(document.getElementById('top').getBBox());
```

```html
<svg id="central">
<text y=10 dominant-baseline="central" >test</text>
</svg>
<svg id="top">
<text y=10 dominant-baseline="top" >test</text>
</svg>
```

See end result:
https://codesandbox.io/s/52wl31l8zn

Comment: God the simple fact that I inverted `textAlignV` and `textAlignH` feels so bad!
Anyway, thank you, it works perfectly. It's such a strange behavior, I don't understand how people are expected to figure that out!